# Can I write a function that takes data from two different tables, transforms it and saves to a third table in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a carpooling service app. I have 2 tables: drivers and passengers. 
I have an algorithm to match users from the 2 tables.

I need a script/function that takes data from the 2 tables, implements the algorithm and saves the output to a third table.

What is the best way to do this? (I'm very new to Django)

Can I make the script/function be executable from the shell?

Comment: Django is a web framework, I'm not sure it's intended to be used for shell applications.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: @Barmar custom management commands linked in comment above, seconded. You can do as much work from the shell as you need/want to.